# recognize link navigated to in iframe by page containing the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a website where all the navigation happens inside of an iframe. all the pages are locally stored on the server.

a reduced version of the html code is:

```
>> index.php

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td>
<iframe src="link.php" width=599 height=350 frameborder=0 scrolling=no name="vframe"></iframe>
<td>
<img src="pic.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Note the img is inside the main page. However, I want this image to change based upon what link is navigated to inside the iframe.

Right now I am using php GET to determine what page has been navigated to, but that is not a great solution because all the user has to do is tinker with the link and the desired image disappears.

eg:

```
<?
   $locate = $_GET['locate'];
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td>
<? { if ($locate =="link") { 

  echo '<iframe src="link.php" width=599 height=350 frameborder=0 scrolling=no name="vframe"></iframe>
    <td>
    <img src="pic.jpg">';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The link inside the iframe page is:

```
http://example.com/index.php?locate=link
```

What I would like to do is somehow have the parent page holding the iframe to recognize what page is inside of the iframe and make the display of the image contingent on that instead of the hack above. I think that would be a more reliable way and not subject to the user manipulating the link.

As an aside, if there is a way to GET 'locate' in the link w/o the link showing in the address bar, that might be a compromise. But as far as I know, that can't be done.

====

EDIT

I found this:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href
```

But I am not sure how to implement it.

I tried

```
<script>document.write(document.getElementById("vframe").contentWindow.location.href );</script>
```

in the body and the head ...

but the iframe link is not displayed

i tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getLink()
  {
  var x=document.getElementById("vframe").contentWindow.location.href;
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="start.php" width=599 height=350 frameborder=0 scrolling=no name="vframe"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

But if it is supposed to work, i can't figure out how to 'read' the result of var x ...

i tried this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="start.php" width=599 height=350 frameborder=0 scrolling=no id="vframe"></iframe>
<script>document.write(document.getElementById("vframe").contentWindow.location.href);</script>

</body>
</html>
```

but the result is "about:blank".  If I place it in the head or above the iframe there is no result ...

Comment: vframe is the name, you need to make it the id

Comment: try `document.write(document.getElementById("vframe").src`

Comment: ok, that is progress ... but the issue now is when i navigate to a different page inside of the iframe your code snip only reads the static link, and doesn't read the new iframe url ... and all the navigation is on the same server ... thanks

Comment: then give a name="vframe" attribute to iframe and then u can access `window.vframe.location.href`

Comment: that returns "about:blank" ... stubborn issue! thanks for the reply